# HTML/CSS button position?

Tags: html, css, button

I have a problem I just can't seem to solve, I just began learning html/css/php, thus please understand my rookie-ness :)

So imagine a website, on that website you have 8 buttons (each being a specific choice).

I wan't to position them equally below and aside each other. So something like this:

[]  []

[]  []

[]  []

[]  []

But my problem is, when I give up the css style position, the button do take that specific position, however the href of the buttons won't work anymore. What is the problem?

Is there perhaps a way to put top and right in the .btn class? I don't think so because I want the 8 button's to have different positions. I think the "style="top; right;" is interfering with the class.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
    background-color: #844903;
    }
    .logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 850px;
    }
    h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    right: 870px;
    color: #a86b00;
    }  
    .btn {
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffc477), color-stop(1, #fb9e25));
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100%);
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100%);
        background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100%);
        background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100%);
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100%);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffc477', endColorstr='#fb9e25',GradientType=0);
        background-color:#ffc477;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-radius:6px;
        border-radius:6px;
        border:1px solid #eeb44f;
        display:inline-block;
        cursor:pointer;
        color:#ffffff;
        font-family:Courier New;
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:17px 24px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #cc9f52;
    }
    .btn:hover {
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fb9e25), color-stop(1, #ffc477));
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fb9e25 5%, #ffc477 100%);
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fb9e25 5%, #ffc477 100%);
        background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fb9e25 5%, #ffc477 100%);
        background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #fb9e25 5%, #ffc477 100%);
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fb9e25 5%, #ffc477 100%);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fb9e25', endColorstr='#ffc477',GradientType=0);
        background-color:#fb9e25;
    }
    .btn:active {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
</style>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Please pick a location:</h1>

    <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo"></div>

     <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="top: 450px; right: 1200px;" href="#" class="btn">1 - 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="top: 450px; right: 1050px;" href="#" class="btn">4 - 6</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td style="top: 540px; right: 1200px;" href="#" class="btn">7 - 9</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td style="top: 540px; right: 1050px;" href="#" class="btn">10+</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g1mueuds/

Thank you very much for your time!

-M

Comment: You can't absolutely position `td`s and `href` is not an accepted attribute for a `td`

Comment: `href` does not work for `td` elements, only `a` elements. It is also worth noticing that tables are meant for tabular data, using them just for layout is considered bad practice nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button><a href="#">1</a></button></td>
        <td><button><a href="#">2</a></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button><a href="#">3</a></button></td>
        <td><button><a href="#">4</a></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button><a href="#">5</a></button></td>
        <td><button><a href="#">6</a></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button><a href="#">7</a></button></td>
        <td><button><a href="#">8</a></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There you go.

EDIT: if you want the to style the buttons, give them a class or id and use that in your CSS file.
i.e. You can use margins and paddings to control where your button is located.

Comment: See my comment below please

Comment: What do you mean bunches up?

Comment: It shows all my buttons in the left-upper-corner of my webpage.

Comment: If you want the buttons to be at a different position then give your table a class and use margins to align it where you want to. e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lvfxq01/

Comment: Sure, 1 more thing, if you're using css rules `top: 10px` or `right: 10px` for example you also need to set the `display` rule for them to work, otherwise stick to margins. Don't forget to vote up please :)

Comment: with display rule you mean absolute, fixed etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

try using `display:block` and display `display:inline-block` . second you should use `<a>` tag. put an `<a>` tag inside a `<td>` tag with `href` property . something like `<td><a href="#">7</a></td>`

Answer (score 0):

@odedta:

It seems very logical what you have shown, however when I try it, it bunches-up my buttons:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="btn"><a href="participants.html">Table 2</a></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn"><a href="participants.html">Table 4</a></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="btn"><a href="participants.html">Table 7</a></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn"><a href="participants.html">Table 8</a></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="btn"><a href="participants.html">F1.12</a></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn"><a href="participants.html">F3.02</a></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="btn"><a href="participants.html">E2.40</a></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn"><a href="participants.html">E2.42</a></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```